# C++ Wconversion warning in constexp functions but not in templates

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

My question is why the following code generates warning **only** for `constexpr` functions but not for templates?

I do understand what warnings mean and how to get rid of them. What I do not understand is why a compiler do not produce warnings for `constexpr` members `ToDouble` and `ToSquare` of a `struct Test` below?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, T value>
struct Test {
  static constexpr double ToDouble = value;

  static constexpr T ToSquare = value * value;
};

template <typename T>
constexpr double ToDouble(T value) {
  return value;
}

template <typename T>
constexpr T ToSquare(T value) {
  return value * value;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << Test<long, 1>::ToDouble << std::endl;
  std::cout << ToDouble(static_cast<long>(1)) << std::endl;

  std::cout << Test<char, 1>::ToSquare << std::endl;
  std::cout << ToSquare(static_cast<char>(1)) << std::endl; 
}
```

```cpp
$ g++ -Wconversion -std=c++11 a.cc 
a.cc: In instantiation of ‘constexpr double ToDouble(T) [with T = long int]’:
a.cc:22:45:   required from here
a.cc:12:10: warning: conversion to ‘double’ from ‘long int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
   return value;
      ^~~~~
a.cc: In instantiation of ‘constexpr T ToSquare(T) [with T = char]’:
a.cc:25:45:   required from here
a.cc:17:16: warning: conversion to ‘char’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
   return value * value;
```

Comment: G++ is doing you a favor by warning you in some cases. It's not required to do so. You're welcome to implement the warning for member initializers and submit a patch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template generates a type.  In each instance of the type the value `value` is a compile time constant.  And it can check for loss of precision.

The `constexpr` case, the template function's generated functions do not have this property.  The argument `value` is not guaranteed to be a compile time constant.  While you only use it in a context where it is a compile time constant, the warning doesn't examine every calling context.

Possibly you misunderstand `constexpr`; on functions it states the function *can be* compile time evaluated, not that it *must be*.

Comment: Thank you Adam! Does that mean that if an expression consists of compile time constants only, the compiler warns a user in case of overflow or altering the value?

Comment: @trula often; try it. `float f = (uint64_t)-1;`.

Comment: Yes, it does here :-) It even does in `Test<char, 15>::ToSquare` in my example below. I'm wondering whether I can rely on this. This would allow me not to use unnecessary `static_cast` in the code